# Angular JS Page Load Issue in IE9

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer

I have an angularjs SPA that is running into problems in IE9. The app works great in Chrome and Firefox. There is quite a bit data to download on the initial load and many dependencies managed through requirejs.

When I view the page in a fresh IE session I get a part of the webpage i.e. some parts just don't display on the screen. I check the network requests and they are short some items. If I reload at this point, the page will load fine because it already cached some of the files so it doesn't need to download them. However if I clear cache and retry the same thing will happen.

Missing files are not consistent, meaning that it's not always the same files.

Additionally, in console I can see the following error:

> $digest already in progress

This app is an open source project that I am intimately familiar with, however I am not sure even where to start troubleshooting this.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You've got something trying to start up a digest cycle when one is already running. You should check directives and any other code you have which calls either $apply() or $digest() directly.

I would try commenting out all of those $apply() and $digest() calls and see what happens. My guess is that the page will load successfully but you might not get everything on it updated. So then you can open another question and we can see what can be done to get rid of the call which is trying to start another digest cycle.

Comment: Thanks John. Any idea why all the files are not being downloaded to the client in IE? Like I mentioned, if I reload the page after the partial load everything works fine.

Comment: My guess is that the JavaScript comes to a grinding halt after the error and you've got some HTML which is only pulled down and inserted via ng-include. Since that's the responsibility of AngularJS to both pull (via an XHR call) and insert, you never get to see it because it isn't going to continue processing the page after that error. That is just a guess though.